# SASS not compiling in Phoenix app

Tags: sass, elixir, phoenix-framework, brunch

I'm just getting started with Phoenix and Elixir, and am coming to a hurdle at the very start with my scss/css files.

Following some blogs/articles, I have done the following so far:

renamed app.css to app.scss

Created new dir '_scss' where I am putthing my scss files.

In app.scss I am importing my scss files.

`@import "../_scss/_foundation.scss";`

`package.json` looks like:

```
{
  "repository": {},
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "brunch build --production",
    "watch": "brunch watch --stdin"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "bourbon": "^4.3.4",
    "bourbon-neat": "^2.0.0",
    "foundation-sites": "^6.3.1",
    "phoenix": "file:deps/phoenix",
    "phoenix_html": "file:deps/phoenix_html",
    "purecss": "^0.6.2",
    "sass-brunch": "^2.10.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-brunch": "~6.0.0",
    "brunch": "2.7.4",
    "clean-css-brunch": "~2.0.0",
    "css-brunch": "~2.0.0",
    "javascript-brunch": "~2.0.0",
    "uglify-js-brunch": "~2.0.1"
  }
}
```

And in `brunch.config.js` I have:

```
stylesheets: {
  joinTo: "css/app.scss",
  order: {
    after: ["web/static/css/app.scss"] // concat app.css last
  }
},
```

I changed the above to reflect the name change of `app.scss`. Was that correct?

And when I load the server, the page loads, but without any styling.  My terminal just seems to be constantly compiling...

`24 Apr 15:01:56 - info: compiling..`

What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

Seems to be the individual file. Int his case foundation.scss. I just tried another framework , Bulma, and it worked instantly.

Comment: Change the `stylesheets` section in your `brunch.config.js` back to just `app.css`.

Comment: that's imported a little custom scss I just added, however main scss still doesn't appear to be loading as I can see plain styling on a number of other elements.  Is this just a case of the server compiling some hefty files?

Comment: I'm talking about the last code block you have in your question. change `app.scss` to `app.css`

Comment: Yes. I now have:
`    stylesheets: {
      joinTo: "css/app.css",
      order: {
        after: ["web/static/css/app.css"] // concat app.css last
      }`

Comment: It shouldn't be taking that long to compile. Have you tried stopping it and starting again? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: restarted a number of times.  No errors at all.